# Reflect-metadata: check if property has "Output()" decorator

Tags: angular, reflect-metadata

I am writing an Angular library. An object wraps an Angular component instance, and this object has to subscribe to all subjects marked with `Output` decorator within the component instance.
This is what I have coded so far inside the constructor:

```
const componentProperties = Object.keys(this.component.instance);
componentProperties.forEach(property => {
    if (!!Reflect.getMetadata('Output', this.component.instance, property)) {
        //do stuff to subscribe
    }
});
```

`Reflect.getMetadata` is returning false also analyzing the property "testEvent" inside the angular component:

```
export class Test2Component implements OnInit {
  public text: string;
  @Output() testEvent = new EventEmitter();
  //...
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

By the moment, I used this hack:

```
 componentProperties.forEach(property => {
      if (
        this.component.instance.constructor.__prop__metadata__ &&
        this.component.instance.constructor.__prop__metadata__[property]
      ) {
        this.component.instance.constructor.__prop__metadata__[property].forEach(decorator => {
          if (Reflect.getPrototypeOf(decorator)['ngMetadataName'] === 'Output') {
            let eventName = decorator.bindingPropertyName ? decorator.bindingPropertyName : property;
            this.registerEvent(property);
            this.emitters.push(eventName);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Very ugly, but it works

Answer (score -1):

I found a better way to do the same thing through `ComponentFactoryResolver`:

```
const factory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component.componentType);
const eventEmitters = factory.outputs;
eventEmitters.forEach(e => {
  this.registerEvent(e.propName, e.templateName);
  this.emitters.push(e.templateName);
});
```